# django ModelForm doesn't seem to validate BooleanField

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

I'm using django 1.5.4

Here's a minimal example of the issue I'm facing.

The model:

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    spam = models.BooleanField()
```

The form:

```
#forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import SampleModel

class SampleModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SampleModel
        fields = ('spam', )
```

From the django shell:

```
>>> data = {} #intentionally blank
>>> form = SampleModelForm(data)
>>> is_valid = form.is_valid() #is_valid is True
>>> form.save() # model instance is created with "spam" set to False by default.
```

Am I validating the form incorrectly? `form.is_valid` validates fields of other types correctly.
The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/) indicate that all fields are required by default but `is_valid` returns `True`without the boolean field key being present.

I need to ensure that the boolean field is present in the input data.
As of now, I'm manually checking if the field is present and is of type `bool`. Do you think I should override `form.is_valid` and add this check so that it can be reused for other models too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out (from code inspection; the docs don't say) that model `BooleanField`s have `blank=True` set automatically in their `__init__` method, thus making the automatically created model form field not required. This makes sense upon consideration (False counts as blank, so `BooleanField`s need it to be true) but it's not obvious when you just read the docs.

If you want it to be required to be `True`, the usual form field overrides apply - declare the field yourself or set its `required` attribute to be `True` somewhere before validating (I usually use the form's `__init__` method). If you want it to allow `True` or `False` but not Python `None`, it's harder.

Specifically, the standard widget for a `BooleanField` is a checkbox. Browsers do not submit anything for unchecked checkboxes, so the checkbox widget treats the absence of the field from the submit as `False`. There's no way to distinguish the user not selecting the checkbox from cases in which the input really is bad. You could use a different widget (say, a `RadioSelect`) to at least make it possible for the browser to submit something for `False`, but you still have the problem that the `BooleanField`'s `to_python` method converts its value to a `boolean` before validating, so you'd have to subclass and override.

Fortunately, `False` is not considered empty by the validation code, so if you do that you'll be able to set `required=True` and don't need custom cleaning methods.

Comment: Thank you! Setting `self.fields['spam'].required = True` in `__init__ `worked. I wanted this behavior for a JSON API.