# Django model.field validators don't execute for required Boolean fields

Tags: django, django-models

**My use case:**

I have a Yes/No question the user must answer, but they may answer it yes or no.  I don't want to supply a default because I need the user to actively select their answer.  If they do not select an answer, I want a form validation error, like "This field is required".

I know that could store this in the DB as a CharField, but I'd prefer to store it as a required BooleanField.  The issue appears to be that the form validation logic does NOT enforce required=True for Boolean fields, nor does it call the model field's custom validators when a value of '' is returned in the POST data.

**My setup:**

```
boolean_choices = (
  (True, 'Yes'),
  (False, 'No'),
)

def boolean_validator(value):
  if value is not True and value is not False:
    raise ValidationError("This field is required.")

class Item(models.Model):
  accept = models.BooleanField(
    choices=boolean_choices,
    validators=[boolean_validator]
  )

class ItemForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = Item
      fields = ['accept']
```

A complete, working demo of the issue is here: 
https://repl.it/@powderflask/django-model-form-validators

**Reproducing the issue**

- create or edit an item, and set the 'accept' value to None ("-------")
  --> save will crash - notice form.is_valid() passed, crash is in form.save()
  --> notice that the boolean_validator did NOT get called.
- create or edit an item and select "Yes" or "No"
  --> save will work fine, and you can see in the terminal that the boolean_validator DID get called.

**My suspicionre**

I suspect that somewhere deep in the form validation logic there is a special case for Boolean fields, which are most often a checkbox (which have a nasty habit of not returning anything in the POST data when not checked).  I suspect that it is difficult to tell between "checkbox not ticked, so False" and "No value returned, so raise RequiredField ValidationError), and the form validation is not treating my use case correctly.

**My Question**
Am I doing something hopelessly stupid here?  Am I missing something?  Should I give up and go have hot bath?
with thanks.

Comment: Normally the `BooleanField` will never obtain something non-bool, since the form field should already handle that. By default a boolean field in a form sets this to `False`.

Comment: I think I've run into this before - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328302/django-modelform-doesnt-seem-to-validate-booleanfield/19328453#19328453 - model `BooleanField`s  have `blank=True` set automatically in their `__init__` method. At least at the time my best idea for how to allow `True` or `False` but not `None` was to subclass the field type.

Comment: Though these days `NullBooleanField` form field might (counterintuitively) be better - that distinguishes a `False` value from `None` and could therefore validate the difference.

Comment: Thanks - great ideas.  The issue seems to be with the default ChoiceField not being set to "required".  If I force the form widget to required, this gets caught by the front-end validation...  Will try some of your ideas - thanks.

Comment: Using NullBooleanField is worse -- not it gets all the way to the DB write before the non-null constraint gets picked up (seemed weird to have a NullBooleanField that could not be nul :-).  Setting model field blank=False explicitly does not change behaviour.

Comment: If you want a user to actively pick Yes or No, using a radio input makes more sense here. And you won't have to deal with empty values.

Comment: Validation of boolean fields is quirky because the default widget for one is a checkbox, and standard browser behavior is that an unset checkbox sends no value - the default behavior in that case is to treat no value as `False`, because that's how the standard widget will provide it. A NullBooleanField on the form will at least not do that, but I admit they're new-ish compared to the last time I looked into this. I agree that it's odd to have a non-null NullBooleanField, but I think your other option is your own custom Field class.

Comment: I turned my suggestions into an answer below - note that I'm recommending using a form `NullBooleanField` as an option to consider, not a model `NullBooleanField`. The latter is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing the [validation documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/) and the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py) of the form field classes reveals the issue and suggests a solution.

A form field handles its input in this order in its `clean` method:

1. call `to_python` to convert the raw value into the correct type
2. call `validate` on the converted value to check for conditions like `required`
3. call `run_validators` on the converted value to check for violations of any registered validator

A `BooleanField`'s `to_python` method turns any input into either `True` or `False`. It cannot return `None` or any other value:

```
class BooleanField(Field):
    widget = CheckboxInput

    def to_python(self, value):
        """Return a Python boolean object."""
        # Explicitly check for the string 'False', which is what a hidden field
        # will submit for False. Also check for '0', since this is what
        # RadioSelect will provide. Because bool("True") == bool('1') == True,
        # we don't need to handle that explicitly.
        if isinstance(value, str) and value.lower() in ('false', '0'):
            value = False
        else:
            value = bool(value)
        return super().to_python(value)
```

This means that no validator can distinguish the situation in which the field was given `None` as a value from a different situation that caused the field to return `False` as the Python parsed value. You can use `required=True` or an explicit validator to enforce that the value must be `True` if you want that, but you can't tell the different reasons the value might be `False` apart.

To do so, you need a different class - one that either treats `None` and anything else you don't want to accept as invalid input before converting it to Python, or one that converts such values to `None` and then can use a validator to reject `None` values.

For the first solution, you could subclass and override `to_python`. The `NullBooleanField` class provides a good example, but we'll adapt it to treat null input as invalid rather than allowing it to return `None`:

```
class StrictBooleanField(Field):

    def to_python(self, value):
        """
        Explicitly check for the string 'True' and 'False', which is what a
        hidden field will submit for True and False, for 'true' and 'false',
        which are likely to be returned by JavaScript serializations of forms,
        and for '1' and '0', which is what a RadioField will submit. Unlike
        the Booleanfield, this field must check for True because it doesn't
        use the bool() function.
        """
        if value in (True, 'True', 'true', '1'):
            return True
        elif value in (False, 'False', 'false', '0'):
            return False
        else:
            raise ValidationError(_('Invalid boolean value %(value)s'), params={'value': value},', code='invalid')
```

For the second option (attractive because it doesn't require a custom field subclass) is to accept a conflict between the field name and the intent and to use a `NullBooleanField` directly, registering a validator that will detect and reject a null value. Something like:

```
def validate_non_null(value):
    if value is None:
        raise ValidationError(_('Value must not be None', code='invalid')

class ItemForm(ModelForm):
    accept = NullBooleanField(validators=[validate_non_null])      

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['accept']
```

Here, we're making use of the `NullBooleanField` to understand the input as `True`, `False`, or `None` rather than just `True` or `False`, and then using standard validation to treat the `None` as recognized but bad input.

Comment: Of course!  Had completely slipped on me that to_python was causing the validation to pass.  Amazing analysis.   A custom Boolean Field seems most appropriate, especially given that NullBooleanField is slated for possible deprecation.  Thank you Peter -- such an excellent answer

Comment: I will also likely override the default form field here too because I found that a "required" BooleanField is not "required" on the widget -- probably because a "required" checkbox means something very distinct.  I'll try to post back a link to a snippet, for posterity.  Thanks again - I see you've well-earned your 26K :-)

Comment: FWIW I don't think `forms.NullBooleanField` is slated for deprecation, just `models.NullBooleanField`. But either way works fine. The changing `required` behavior is indeed a consequence of checkbox support - specifying the field to use your custom class should also let you explicitly set `required=True`, but you'll also need to override `validate`. `BooleanField`'s `validate` requires that the value be `True`, not just present (checkbox logic). https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1019 is where model `BooleanField`s have special form field logic.

Comment: Thanks - I got confused -- though you were talking models fields above - now see it is Form Fields.   All good.  Much appreciate your help with this -- very glad to gain a deeper appreciation for the validation logic.

Comment: You're right, I wrote "model field classes" when I meant "form field classes" above. Oops!

Comment: For posterity, here is a django-snippet with the StrictBooleanField: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10672/
and a working proto-type that shows it usage: https://repl.it/@powderflask/django-model-form-validators-3

Comment: That snippet will treat `False` values as invalid, because you're raising the `ValidationError` on `if not value` - you're ending up with basically the default behavior of a required `BooleanField`. I think I'd keep the comparison as `if value is None:` instead.

Comment: Ha!  Yup -- still adding some tests, I'll get it right eventually :-)  Thanks Peter